# Flatten Array in CouchDb

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I'm learning CouchDb, And I have a problem

I have two documents

```
{
   "_id": "2a8b8edb5d47c1e9fbafd414f60023af",
   "_rev": "4-e305faba47bcb08569d225b181ba927e",
   "skills": [
       "js",
       "php"
   ],
   "type": "user",
   "age": 32
}

{
   "_id": "2a8b8edb5d47c1e9fbafd414f6002443",
   "_rev": "4-edbfaa004143fc65df823f60b7f9ee94",
   "skills": [
       "js",
       "nodejs",
       "angular"
   ],
   "type": "user",
   "age": 28
}
```

I want to retrive  an array like

```
['js','php','nodejs','angular']
```

without duplicate. I tried with this map

```
function(doc) {
var user = [];
for (item in doc.skills) {
  user.push(doc.skills[item]);
} 
  emit( doc.type, user);
}
```

I got

```
["js", "php"]
["js", "nodejs", "angular"]
```

I tried with this reduce

```
function (key, skills){
 var skill = [];
 skill.push(skills);
 return skill
}
```

and the result is

```
[[["js", "nodejs", "angular"], ["js", "php"]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your reduce function, `skills` is a list of lists of skills, so you need to concatenate each one onto the result:

```
function(key, skills) {
  var result = [];
  var seen = {};
  skills.forEach(function(s) {
    s.forEach(function(skill) {
      if (seen[skill])
        return;
      seen[skill] = true;
      result.push(skill);
    });
  });
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but In this way I have this Result: `["js", "nodejs", "angular", "js", "php"]`. I'd like to have `js` only one time. Like AddToSet of mongoDb

Comment: Then you just need to keep track of which skills you've already seen; see edit.